# PHPStorm and other JetBrains IDE's: how to change default git colors?

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm

I'm currently using [PHPStorm 6 EAP build](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/12/phpstorm-webstorm-6-eap-build-123-66/) and git, but answer to this question could be useful for someone using other JetBrains IDE's or different version control systems.

How to change default git colors in tabs and project files window? I switched to "Darcula" IDE theme and now I couldn't normally see file names.

Comment: a) I think the best place to ask this would be with JetBrains directly and b) it's not a programming question.

Comment: @markus FAQ [clearly states](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) that **software tools commonly used by programmers** category is for this site ..?

Comment: I would count an IDE as a meta tool, not a software tool.

Comment: I would just move this to SuperUser or Programmers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | File Status